# Infinite scroll/loop/movement of an image array using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider, infinite-loop, infinite-scroll

So I've searched almost everywhere for this, and I guess just the way I've implemented it and want to continue to use it, it's making it difficult to find a solution. Any who I'm trying to have an infinite scroll of the 4 images in my array as slider items. I just don't like the way the component jumps to the first image in the array when it gets to the end. The slider images are controlled by arrows. I'm using styled components so can ignore that code, just wanted to include for full picture of the component.

I think there are packages available to solve this issue, but I would like to know how to code the solution without that assistance. Code below:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components';
import ArrowLeftIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowLeft';
import ArrowRightIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowRight';
import { sliderItems } from '../data';
import { mobile } from '../responsive';

const Container = styled.div`
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
`;

const Arrow = styled.div`
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: ${props => props.direction === "left" && "10px"};
    right: ${props => props.direction === "right" && "10px"};
    margin: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 2;
    ${mobile({width:"30px", height:"30px"})}
`;

const Wrapper = styled.div`
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    transform: translateX(${props =>props.slideIndex * -100}vw);
    transition: transform 1.5s ease-in-out;
`;

const Slide = styled.div`
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
`;

const ImgContainer = styled.div`
    height: 100%;
    flex: 1;
`;

const Image = styled.img`
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
`;

const InfoContainer = styled.div`
    margin-left: 50px;
    flex: 1;
    padding: 10px;
    ${mobile({
        display: "none"
    })}
`;

const Title = styled.h1`
    font-size: 60px;
`;

const Desc = styled.p`
    margin: 50px 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
`;

const Button = styled.button`
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 25px;
    background-color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 4px;
    transition: all 0.25s ease;
    &:hover {
        transform: scale(1.05);
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
    }
`;

const Slider = () => {

    const [slideIndex, setSlideIndex] = useState(0);

    const handleClick = (direction) => {

        if(direction === "left"){
            setSlideIndex(slideIndex > 0 ? slideIndex - 1 : 3);
        }else{
            setSlideIndex(slideIndex < 3 ? slideIndex + 1 : 0);
        }
    };


    return (
        <Container>
            <Arrow direction="left" onClick={() => handleClick("left")}>
                <ArrowLeftIcon />
            </Arrow>
            <Wrapper slideIndex={slideIndex}>
                {sliderItems.map(item => (
                    <Slide key={item.id}>
                        <ImgContainer>
                            <Image src={item.img} alt={item.alt}/>
                        </ImgContainer>
                        <InfoContainer>
                            <Title>{item.title}</Title>
                            <Desc>{item.desc}</Desc>
                            <Button>Shop Now</Button>
                        </InfoContainer>
                    </Slide>
                ))}
            </Wrapper>
            <Arrow direction="right" onClick={() => handleClick("right")}>
                <ArrowRightIcon />
            </Arrow>
        </Container>
    )
}

export default Slider;
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: And yes the function I have 'handleClick' is what causes it to jump from end of array to beginning and vice-versa, that's just because I haven't been able to create logic for the solution I'm looking for. 

Also will be changing hardcoded index to Array.length - if anyone has an issue with that as they read my code :D

Comment: What should happen on the last image? You shouldn't be able to move to the first image? Or, the right arrow should disappear?

Comment: So assume direction I'm clicking is 'right'. Once I get to last slide it should render the first slide but continue to go to the right direction instead of jumping back to the first slide. 

I saw a solution where I could clone the first slide but that didn't really make sense. Spoke to some people about removing the first element and putting that at the end of the slide but that didn't really work. 

And vice versa when direction is left